# Question already exists but outdated?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I'm seeing a lot of people asking a question I have relating to node.js express.

Almost all the answers include bits of code which have been deprecated and no longer work with Express 4.

Is it best to re-ask the question specifying Express 4 and link to the old answer explaining it doesn't work? Or is something else preferable?

Comment: Is the question already tagged in a way where a express 4 answer would be acceptable?  If so I would raise a bounty.

Comment: Looks like we could edit it to make it apply to both versions.  I'll let meta decide if that is okay.  I'll even fund the bounty for it if you do not want to lose your rep.  You would have to pick out the answer to reward though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bounty reason for that:

> #### Current answers are outdated
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

Remember, you can always sacrifice a bit of narrowness as long as the main question remains the same: How to do X?

If there's no indication of a problem specific to that version, you can simply strip it out and allow more general answers to be given. Who knows, you may get a version agnostic answer.